# Surface Pro 9 sticks at shutdown, how to trace the problem?

Tags: shutdown, freeze, journalctl

I tried installing three distros on SP9: Ubuntu 22.04.1, Ubuntu 22.10, KaliLinux 2022.3, there is problem with all these distros that it sticks at shutdown.

After typing `shutdown now` in terminal, the screen immediately goes black, but it keeps running at background, because after a period of time, it becomes pretty warm. And I can't boot it up by pressing the power button, I have to hold it 10 seconds to force a shutdown and reboot it.

I tried to investigate in journal log, this is what I did:

1. at **00:05:xx**, I shut it down with `shutdown now`
2. at **00:10:xx**(5 minutes later), I force a shutdown by holding the power button for 10 seconds
3. at **00:15:xx**(5 minutes later), boot

The log looks like:

```
...
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd-journald[380]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali haveged[591]: haveged: Stopping due to signal 15
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali haveged[591]: haveged starting up
Nov 11 00:05:11 kali systemd-journald[380]: Journal stopped
-- Boot 27ff4460b72f4ca095979e4cdee7fc2f --
Nov 11 00:15:17 kali kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x421, date = 2022-06-15
...
```

From the log, I dont't see why it sticks. And SP9 is a new device, there isn't much information about using linux on it yet, how to trace the problem?